# Можно ли сказать "за этим я живу"?

Tags: фразеология

Возник спор по поводу выражения "за этим я живу". Оппонент утверждает, что так говорить можно, а я утверждаю, что правильнее говорить "для этого я живу" или "ради этого я живу". Хотелось бы прочитать правильный, обоснованный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это выражение возможно, хотя и в крайне редких ситуациях.

```
Я живу за высоким забором, но не за тем, деревянным. Видишь каменный, с зубцами? За этим я и живу.
```

Что касается "смысла жизни", такое выражение возможно только в риторике диалога и при специфических условиях. Если отвечать на вопрос "**зачем ты живёшь?**", то, используя элементы риторики из вопроса, можно ответить "**затем, чтобы...**" и даже просто "**а затем!**" А найдя в поле зрения смысл жизни (детишек своих и т.п.), можно указать на "него" и добавить: "**Вот за этим! За этим я и живу.**" Здесь такое выражение делает возможным только форма вопроса.

В широком же смысле уместнее выражение "для/ради этого я и живу".